# preg_replace expression help needed for PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

Trying to strip some BBCode from some text. I would like to remove everything between a [img] and a [/img], using a PHP preg_replace function, for example:

```
Here is my image[img]http://www.abc.com/image1.jpg[/img] and more text
```

Match: [img] followed by any number of characters followed by [/img]

Result:

```
Here is my image and more text
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's not working. I tried /\\[\i\m\g\\]/ and that seemed to match [img]. It's the rest of the string I cannot figure out.

Comment: Read up some tutorials on http://regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 2):

First, find the pattern that would match your BBCode tag:

```
\[img\][^\[]+\[/img\]
```

The only hard part is the class `[^\]]`. The `\[` means any opening bracket and the ^ means NOT. So this class will match everything that is not a `[`.
You could also replace the class with `.+` and use the U (ungreedy) option.

Now that you now which pattern to use, you just have to replace it with... an empty string. And the job is done!

This is a very basic regexp, it's important that you understand it and that you are able to reproduce it

Answer (score 1):

```
/\[img\].*?\[\/img\]/i
```

will take care of everything between `[img]` and `[/img]` (case in-sensitive)

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to group your content e.g. '/[img](.+)[\/img]/i', so in you replace condition you can reference the value between the tags '<img src="$1" />'